Azure data factory copies subnode parent of json files to another blob storage
I have multiple JSON files, and I am searching for the specific elements of the file's content. If there is a match, copy the parent node  and children nodes inside the {metadata} to another storage.
So far, it copies the entire JSON file to another blob storage if it matches the criteria.
Sample.json:
{
"record": {
    "org":{
        "name": "School",
         "postalCode": "40121"
    },
    "metadata": {
         "an": "file6.json",
         "markings": {
              "document": {
                 "distribution": {
                    "code": "A"
                  }
               }     
          },
         "publicationDate": {
               "date": "2022-11-25"
          }
     }
  }
}

if condition match then result sample.json only have metadata{..} will be copy to another storage:
    "metadata": {
         "an": "file6.json",
         "markings": {
              "document": {
                 "distribution": {
                    "code": "A"
                  }
               }     
          },
         "publicationDate": {
               "date": "2022-11-25"
          }
     }
  

But my ADF copies entire json to another storage.


Is the second JSON should be your expected output? and is the JSON file result should be like {"metadata":{...}} or only the meta data object?

Json file result should be {"metadata":{...all the children nodes..}}

Check the below answer and let me know if it worked or not.

You can achieve your requirement by using a temporary csv file.
Create a temporary csv file like below.
one
1

After checking your condition, create a set variable activity with below expression inside your if activity True activities. Enable the firstRow in the lookup activity
@concat('{"metadata":',activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.record.metadata,'}')

Here, I have skipped the if activity.

Then take a copy activity with the above temporary CSV dataset as source. In the additional columns, create a new column new and give the above variable in the dynamic expression like below.

In the sink, create a CSV dataset and you can use dataset parameter for the filename. Give the below configurations so that it creates a JSON file using csv dataset.

Give your required target file name as <fiename>.json to the above parameter.
Now, go to the mapping of the copy activity and give the below expression as dynamic content.
@json('{
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "mappings": [
                                        {
                                            "source": {
                                                "name": "new",
                                                "type": "String"
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "type": "String",
                                                "physicalType": "String",
                                                "ordinal": 1
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }')


Now, run the pipeline and it will create the required JSON files for each iteration like below.

